# Trigger error System.QueryException: Variable does not exist

Tags: apex, trigger, master-detail

I have two custom Objects Member and Issue.

Issue has a master detail relationship with member. The field called MASTER of Issue is a master-detail field that points to Member object.

I'm creating a trigger to update a field of member based on certain criterion:

```
trigger RollbackUpdate on sade__Issue__c (before insert, before update) {
    for (sade__Issue__c childObj : Trigger.new) {
        if(childObj.sade__Approval_Status__c != null && childObj.sade__Approval_Status__c.equals('Rejected')){
            Id mID = Id.valueOf(childObj.sade__Member__c);
            sade__Member__c me = Database.query('SELECT Id,sade__Membership_ID__c,sade__No_of_Books_Issued__c FROM sade__Member__c WHERE Id =:'+mID+'  LIMIT 1');
            me.sade__No_of_Books_Issued__c -= 1;
            update me;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I'm rejecting an approval I get this issue:

> RollbackUpdate: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by:
>   System.QueryException: Variable does not exist: a0H28000002IOujEAG

But I do have a member with ID a0H28000002IOujEAG.
Workbench Query `SELECT Id,Name FROM sade__Member__c WHERE Name = 'Abhishek De'` returns:

```
    Id                  Name
1   a0H28000002IOujEAG  Abhishek De
```

Comment: sade__Member__c me = [SELECT Id,sade__Membership_ID__c,sade__No_of_Books_Issued__c FROM sade__Member__c WHERE Id =:mID LIMIT 1];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

Issue in you query you need to add `Id =\''+mID+'\'`

```
sade__Member__c me = Database.query('SELECT Id,sade__Membership_ID__c,sade__No_of_Books_Issued__c FROM sade__Member__c WHERE Id =\''+mID+'\'   LIMIT 1');
```

For a side note.. Your DML and query inside for loop. Store `sade__Member__c` in a list and update outside of for loop.  Do same for query as well.

Else you can hit governor limit..

Comment: Thanks. This works. However -1 update is not working. Can you help?

Comment: @AbhishekDey are you getting any error?

Comment: Update is not happening.

Comment: @AbhishekDey Can you replace this line ` me.sade__No_of_Books_Issued__c -= 1;` with `me.sade__No_of_Books_Issued__c =  me.sade__No_of_Books_Issued__c != null ? me.sade__No_of_Books_Issued__c - 1 : 0;` this and try